# Factorial with caching with static int array

Tags: java, caching, runtime, factorial

```
static int count = 0;
static long[] cache = new long[3000];

static {
    cache[0] = 1;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        factorial_with_cache(2999);
    }
    System.out.println(count);        
}

public static long factorial_with_cache (int n){
    if (cache[n] != 0){
        return cache[n];
    }
    cache[n] = n * factorial_with_cache(n - 1);
    count++;
    return cache[n];
}
```

I built a function that calculates factorials using a cache (ignoring overflow).

But its runtime isn't any better compares to non-caching function and I found that caching isn't working correctly.

Because I expected a variable 'count' to be 2999 after loop but I fount it is 293465 which is a lot more than that. (without loop, it prints 2999)

What is to wrong with this function?

Comment: because your function is recursive and you do count++ in it

Comment: But when I remove the loop and only executes the function for 2999, it prints 2999. Is it still because of recursion? (sum of integers from 1 to 3000 is 4501500 which is close to 4305710)

Comment: @Sean Yes. Because inside your function, you call *the same function* again. So when calling it with 2999, it gets executed once and then 2998 times afterwards. By the time all calls have returned, `count++` was executed 2999 times.

Comment: the third and fourth line from the bottom cause count to exceed 2999
lets say i have int x is 0 and my method dostuff does x++, if i call dostuff inside of dostuff then x is going to be infinite ( will cause stackoverflow) because it would keep repeating itself!

Comment: I am sorry. I still don't get it, and I edited a question a little bit. How can "count" be different after looping? Shouldn't every factorial already be cached in the array after the first loop?

Comment: @Sean I've added an answer which I hope you can understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the range of **long** datatype:

> long  8 bytes (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to  9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

your factorial gives the positive values till you are searching for factorial of 25.
And latter 25 , the value of factorial which are calculated is coming negative (It means you are overflowing long) and your count will work as expected till 65 factorial is calculated (till negative value) and then the value for factorial 66 it reaches to 0..

just try below by printing factorial:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          long fact=factorial_with_cache(66);
          System.out.println(fact);
        }
        System.out.println(count);
```

And the count will be printed as

> **(forLoopCount*(number-65))+65** , In your case (100*(2999-65))+65 is 293465

becuase the value for factorial it traces back in cache which is not zero is 65th element (at 64 index).

Answer (score 1):

So, let me break it down to you!.

The factorial value of 2999 is `13831198678126180285189556976955373903170397316439366392298225525658528550411773166953335884059334473358394878461205706165250290371348635931517800720356113203873679301399725840687554463393227601721573232498656280819242922032367667908703698446747042372944385912938442812976579204340368770976791467161792908482026536763476497016597962706920837208377639001547222987372530067858391829660217859289638428364594156664891566396944031170356121274762354507422848113071258383496196034678939603033097637499047300169646331468238450491051510529147169986724755958362486789324705690789582425714662973561230539501202732819906031261484507986168459203695503720787715306962036185816958171315101812071237299383615730698142124734425009998777928314671591890471560274735833304904959453223240212984890196653392856493421129589037623689334983609133572374939825462133789731181451373437595533811597516653047843373551034468875167743673579450500731701049557870779579798365517154053116338596649981357437001475641612713380485162624246015285341187194401439315317685276897783748963573748717156161769574677089322363037849660911158458585633121725465474927244487503626338581145799640164089032772344644035725447994450814858680158855133471471566493328118184865933128900946476171137729637721898436949504508364668715924682335777135513931476001478897301228489756952423900549337170685817482869322924594934553551003036605213030431370211238540513634600045019557208087444634144722209572173742863424856277834965975623123264292792298280478857955478985025157988294085407394460004866920398953072534411602822485072110137246001443714741975414563519594304969324628586261528579942898463434127945755294142551435479172585965738348357120600576683876141492098075828585209276254499589065093789637861306274833094913863894376778010733315584027638295254781954610771181735025318637354022424432317128707664886202509105961484149955116054723079614963020498616978124480963271628142440605710424177963844835527047941127068625126602868360296587251294298750977877916818183056200089076530408509618194827562218441437670451251604136520412562026002566902646513949635716489125951469176102624329367970981707309954931234483752478815193819919046940901995441721784302194857041195090070644484327035189466269961364993448728359341757679578928014056475745993488101416681676935545677586672113973814268569600810283522630702882325818379846373279545389063433426048793378977494110923865060198731023168079278694206856962403099309932476468192292446106625814895181431600107247018896474570181676290139870638357579666677214004824737774431290539343185204668200955800140961796618216776009476171707432009598580600540607745366106990480349004177689104965384412262911661517983201465683450782588737131971506423474040743808999564029154506993562074784937792064798377314289371162177187409391071658827235127282051775532062510098826200386957421213481307419200642164870305628383671047981858132767730852384720717147489707456839716365953949812050321036644546531520598864465617319535112877058774715688947419064131580843908826519916664427749093269298823584351338064696733536570891584395455175134404252585951310232510018865069402485833157299381484590749402629481111706181867189617902727630965072766713218125649095472925555254271796579113386470181227145145782044748230689023360927474548519150294185556719080917603439047213543803560461443641342427106320294937680221742056517608545727954154981431896286464615575574564733158523773515339421141910343038451177576269394257673865595696145764470705694837193543322565755533887878425653323007167374034984753189092864395172089482366791478206807334511797067912797698473565007162069130217730303607114778083832632094745399523891591282708699147685012083622118240243657099361565732179240926631053400186908352669170802498149387797404799372830916093992885059492849249732904712828347430127984696856947346045759045222567855013693926840231677378744507230913510338446973920611359605911891548916357205533551076812967546595355169668436624145148563105200443314135704098338484590507017314148504265121657071624074064576429719944333914132659197510167106279294498294744074169106272133146311875939034291810862931519619247593463572388793752634599383049481842295290543310338170244405184924421525345305394766236107745856279305711691002008912764098229027010250648673458812712892369111259770860752452145178192387601343493641928636582411137977634690746620001816089765370131213375846513299799140007308422976207521653093045456515661082438164698099164737736238987887604321282063792704869736900344337373311421647222149710103632831178455467277094227704168859462141968845732336969092143110178250432445572309805015956983080592707178326499816577452815043403343240119997858835910187898983513330297084001603373363523211048122726398082654521129700828750257789083133267241150542349616716479447911942146684493824985807109624549493196517947945459425200477792599605375618154135498044805373036317551108920542553407043626403888641459832178279343412021431660661847004770522200579839513142002891066188195561545147576726674097535863255730732789176509455052905173962566105999668617707172897012592225627884763749139942033144845223843137607945870705185228736818194603451718134984572823575454406177591828833937000873777076143286975370719857688674644025825580933636487558107379601763547689237092321337911968750350350207856080439217177676925119658378188382474722467172490240279700623329997759788303630895974913235271384285181321984740867973019755275212448225468786508612988993837327986628867894584347339330109395315189804183506355434284956511125894328200010602697940710012700738129019153727101417320638801990152011727707236050552882452185513510976137249542985694285597433351175282125687093530484011848796644042625302116542612658623784196206071084087859012798734245795108302784560165996695233840827767813175065781551114331550855078698914278183507913244634124753936290599761240761788764479746965254304384814035524536401827280713121964622571847614159091700055578119247697879649481521588125728024624793157002622383690149851552542093855379183576921256026866677281432077992602744437119929192378994337605857208557227762427170645778895263145703032582860407622708941374105757560394991735954484369165110569420051053146751215121841484529317344915071143082972214834934785117427325907327323956351628058965466260901594022042307157516206082619875478093063424834484331589789332405761721821863933157263022628562426191490028096574592744921026913639837655412782142613217955005774888616730714697231543457088527065900258227520678399439594304530337999272434545057921568904794664270097074820282773506327749449618377008513240527728310551223577424390998477250258491878249375773652218477283959862326057497240566955256032969442610279413479245991485114175229570966285171060322337499286484763536542456863553323594724246140240535192263020188389231521830040129388591953979743641454327796516619093291507799363499952822494950133169703132944736808231037872625326203934365369591454254996804885055848502537888575304997792038113414587636763461378629510437530377514949741965335728283723130064661811549805161260779434177122925330001814574110967154189394698666276840840528442866611330112198472977565560054421966452744887749026774673476597119141918499516457632064030550264890665707146610860517981945041882670296628962352294237074209578011924139474934410391009112814073534671869747359856497734981269800821854176767776274721767346002013762814794961396376464661990588556737167203780040389785178621661600980521079426482525438347561911423287705520933644054859388470137299692798736919535048363842176140811215743626823029475470841708861576378019731723918097050874000743252328975986374873654787685684044366405474086145883963064543443283741094316935375400191188518071061185279429772712931980320767930925743448141144113853867852863500774825091500876956610471375132123918137870632423052883572240769361145098526133695745342449000372928715411061813143685686161256824935345001518961673534243407418799210246313328341659385060893305664721381846776636604396835551452718885897176356302728734712814697152118430414021633905812143491151730458640971651094329383936246692244495665898440957150263861482901326801912557851925957864645963859049318674446902818797438056706130851744872706591971891128651973088423541354578092586738615503678456019321106904965647554452856791768609892202741402821821519518889296407542539996754653930879152617217513639585536181286553740648082906808320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` [find it yourself](http://coolconversion.com/math/factorial/_2999_)

I know its a lot of scrolling :P

Okay, now during your iterations, **factorial of 20** will be `2,432,902,008,176,640,000` and **factorial of 21** will be `51,090,942,171,709,440,000` and maximum value for `long` in java is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` so, here your `cache[19]` will be `-4,249,290,049,419,214,848` and `cache[65]` will be `0`. which makes all values till cache[2999] to `0`. So, every time you call the method `factorial_with_cache`, it's not serving from cache, but calculating every time (because you're checking `if(cache[n] != 0)` then return from cache else calculate) causing the count value `293465` instead of `2999`.

I've modified the code a little for your understanding.

```
public class Test2 {
    static int count = 0;
    static long[] cache = new long[3000];

    static {
        cache[0] = 1;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
            factorial_with_cache(2999);
    }

    public static long factorial_with_cache (int n){
        if (cache[n] != 0){
            return cache[n];
        }
        cache[n] = n * factorial_with_cache(n - 1);
        System.out.println("Factorial(" + n + ") is " + cache[n]);
        count++;
        return cache[n];
    }
}
```

This will print your calculated fact values.

```
public class Test2 {
    static int count = 0;
    static long[] cache = new long[3000];

    static {
        cache[0] = 1;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            factorial_with_cache(2999);
            System.out.println("i[" + i + "] count[" + count +"]");
        }
    }

    public static long factorial_with_cache (int n){
        if (cache[n] != 0){
            return cache[n];
        }
        cache[n] = n * factorial_with_cache(n - 1);
        count++;
        return cache[n];
    }
}
```

This will print count value for each iteration.